# Can I add a key value pair to a get link?

Tags: php, arrays

Ok I'm new to php and I'm already loving my progress. So now I'm doin something just for fun. I have 2 pages. The first page has a link to the second page like this:

```
<h2>You can click the link below to skip to the next page</h2>
<a href="page2.php?food=rice&dress=lacoste">Click Here</a>"
```

Now on the second page, I successfully got the value for food by using the get array like this

```
$food = $_GET['food'];
echo $food;
```

Now my problem is, how do I add a new item to the array like for instance chicken. Is this possible? If it is please show me how. Thanks guys =)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make your link look something like this

```
<a href="page2.php?food[]=rice&food[]=chicken&dress=lacoste">Click Here</a>"
```

Note the `[]` at the end of the parameter. This means the argument will be passed to PHP as an array. If you do a `print_r($_GET['food']);` you will get an array with both `rice` and `chicken` as elements

Answer (score 0):

you could set `food=rice-chicken` in the url and break the string up in php.